# How to create and feed a Tensor including tuples

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I would like to run tensorflow on an input tensor that is composed by some values plus a tuple of data.

The original values are stored in a list of ndarrays of type float32 and size 3000 x 10 x 2 (time serie of 3000 observations of 2 variables, with a 'look back' period of 10 days). Let's call it 'X_val'.

Tuples, which represent my supervised input, are of type (0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1) and are stored into another list (more precisely an ndarray object of numpy module) of size 3000 x 10 x 2. Let's call it 'X_label'.

Now I would like to feed these two arrays 'X_val' and 'X_label' into the tf.variable 'X' that I expect will have size of 3000 x 10 x 3 (2 values + 1 tuple) so to run the network (rnn with lstm), the cost function and the adam optimizator function.
Here all my tries are miserably failing.

For completeness the 'Y' (ie the target value) is an array of type float32 and size 3000 x 10 x 1.

I am not sure how to proceed. May I have some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: provide some working code will be helpful for other people to provide help.

Comment: @scott huang: My question is quite generic as I don't actually have a 'presentable' piece of code to get deep into the question, as this is part of a long application and it is split into different parts of it. I would therefore need to rewrite it ad-hoc to make it coprehensible. 
Until I wont have this ready, I am just looking for an indication on the feasibility of the idea (or indication of where I can find some literature on this subject). Thanks